# Issue saving a .xls file to .xlsx from C#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2008

I am getting this error only when I try to save (Save as.) the file as .xlsx from .xls from c#. It only occurs when I try to run from IIS 7.0

---

```
The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:

• Make sure the specified folder exists. 

• Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.

• Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *

• Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.

The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:
```

---

according to my situation the path exists, folders and files are not read only, doesnt contain any of these characters and no characters more than 218.

it works when I locally run the project with file path and file name as below,

```
"\\localhost\inetpub\wwwroot\ABC\GeneratedReports\Financial\Ageing_XXXX XXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXX_10_15548312.xls"
```

If the path is changed to below again this gives that error

```
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ABC\Generatedreports\Financial\Ageing_XXXX XXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXX_10_15548312.xls"
```

---

This is the snippet that I use to convert these excel files

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook_temp = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(strSavePath, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

xlWorkbook_temp.SaveAs(Filename: strSavePath2, FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
xlWorkbook_temp.Close();
```

Comment: Is the machine where IIS is running the same as your development machine? Also, does the user for your IIS Application Pool have permissions to that folder?

Comment: Please provide the exception details, it can prove useful to resolving the issue.

Comment: Yes it is the same machine. I have given permission for everyone and IIS_IUSER as well. Yet the same. Also I do many formatting changes to the excel file it is allowed. Only problem is to 'save as' a excel workbook file(.xlsx) @MerkleGroot

Comment: The first segment of this issue is the exception that I get @JakubJankowski

Comment: Any chance that you have the file open in Excel while this is running? Excel has a tendency to lock open spreadsheets.

Comment: @MerkleGroot Nope it doesnt. Only from the program it self to 'SaveAs' xlOpenXMLWorkbook